# Out-of-line member template function definition using another member template function in the signature

Tags: c++11, templates, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

I ran into this problem in some real-life C++11 code, but I boiled it down to this:

```
template<int i> struct Dummy {};

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  template<int i> static constexpr int bar() { return i; }

  template<int i>
  static auto working() -> Dummy<bar<i>()>;

  template<int i>
  static auto also_working() -> Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()>;

  template<int i>
  static Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> not_working();
};

template<typename T> template<int i>
auto Foo<T>::working() -> Dummy<bar<i>()> {
  return Dummy<bar<i>()>{};
}

template<typename T> template<int i>
auto Foo<T>::also_working() -> Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> {
  return Dummy<bar<i>()>{};
}

template<typename T> template<int i>
Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working() {
  return Dummy<bar<i>()>{};
}
```

I was trying to create an out-of-line definition of a template member function of a template class, where the signature of the function involved calling another template member function and started out with something like the `not_working()` function. The problem was that the definition failed to match the declaration.

Clang said:

```
clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -std=c++11   -c -o out_of_line.o out_of_line.cc
out_of_line.cc:28:42: error: out-of-line definition of 'not_working' does not match any declaration in 'Foo<T>'
Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working() {
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

GCC said:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11   -c -o out_of_line.o out_of_line.cc
out_of_line.cc:28:34: error: prototype for ‘Dummy<bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()’ does not match any in class ‘Foo<T>’
 Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working() {
                                  ^~~~~~
out_of_line.cc:14:43: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<int i> static Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()
   static Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> not_working();
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

By trial and error I discovered that using a trailing return type I could get the definition to match the declaration, yielding the `also_working()` function. Once there I realized that due to the change of scope in the trailing return type I could do away with some name qualification, yielding the much prettier `working()` function.

Now I wonder why the `not_working()` function is not working, i.e. why its definition does not match its declaration (I could just settle in ignorance with the solution I found, but I'm likely to encounter more of this kind of issues and I don't want to waste more time using trial and error); does the bug lie within the compilers or within my code. I've read through *14.6 Name resolution [temp.res]* but I'm not sure what rules are applicable for this case.

**Clarification of the question**: Given the rules in the C++11 standard:

1. should the `not_working()` definition match the declaration?
2. which rules are involved in determining 1.?
3. how do the rules from 2. interact when determining 1.?

Comment: Strange but true... The same code using C++14 variable templates [compiles fine with _g++_, but still doesn't compile with _clang++_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a38e2c0fecf64abe). Looks like a compiler bug for me.

Comment: While not addressing this particular issue, [this core language issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2) contains an answer suggesting that the intention is to let out-of-line definitions match declarations with textually matching signatures.

Comment: One of those places where `auto` helps with types you can't write. gcc and clang are both happy with `auto Foo<T>::working();` as far as I can tell, and will deduce the return type when they need it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to implement [CWG2](http://wg21.link/cwg2) but is possibly doing things in a surprising order. Looking at gcc's errors:

```
prog.cc:28:34: error: prototype for 'Dummy<bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()' does not match any in class 'Foo<T>'
 Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working() {
                                  ^~~~~~
prog.cc:14:43: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<int i> static Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()
   static Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> not_working();
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The definition is seen with the return type `Dummy<bar<i>()>` but the candidate declaration has return type `Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<i>()>`. Specifically, the `Foo<T>::` qualification on `bar<i>` has been lost.

Changing the definition of `also_working` to have return type `Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<2>()>`, we get useful parallel errors:

```
prog.cc:23:6: error: prototype for 'Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<2>()> Foo<T>::also_working()' does not match any in class 'Foo<T>'
 auto Foo<T>::also_working() -> Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<2>()> {
      ^~~~~~
prog.cc:11:15: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<int i> static Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<i>()> Foo<T>::also_working()
   static auto also_working() -> Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()>;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here the definition is seen with the return type `Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<2>()>` (as written), and the candidate declaration has return type `Dummy<Foo<T>::bar<i>()>`.

Clearly, `Foo<T>::bar<i>` is different from `bar<i>` *even in the context of `Foo<T>`*, since removing `Foo<T>::template` out of either the declaration or definition of the return type of `also_working` makes it stop working. (Taking both out gets you back `working`.)

I tried changing the declaration of `not_working` to be:

```
  template<int i>
  static Dummy<bar<i>()> not_working();
```

and now gcc complains:

```
prog.cc:28:34: error: prototype for 'Dummy<bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()' does not match any in class 'Foo<T>'
 Dummy<Foo<T>::template bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working() {
                                  ^~~~~~
prog.cc:14:26: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<int i> static Dummy<bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()
   static Dummy<bar<i>()> not_working();
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which is pretty clearly nonsensical, since we have character-for-character-comparable declaration and definition `Dummy<bar<i>()> Foo<T>::not_working()`, once the compiler's done with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a bout with GCC, but IMHO the fact that a particular compiler is failing at matching the definition with the declaration does not answer the question. I was looking for the particular rules involved, telling me if the definition should match the declaration according to the standard regardless of the compiler used. Re-reading my question I see that it's apparently too vague: I'll update it to be more specific. Sorry if my vagueness misled you.

Comment: Well, you already have *that* answer in the comments, that the ordering is currently vague in the specification, and CWG issue 2 is intended to fix that, but has not yet been worded and submitted. What I was trying to answer is _why_ it doesn't work. It happens that gcc gives us clues to what it's trying to match, while clang is just saying "Didn't match".